# Add additional parameters into event subscriber

Tags: symfony, events, listener

I am using symfony 3. I already created some events and they work fine. But this new event is different. I must somehow send some additional parameters to subscriber. What is the best way to do that? I created phenstalk service to perform job. The controller dispatch an event like:

```
$dispatcher = $this->container->get('event_dispatcher');
    $dispatcher->dispatch(Events::POWERPLANT_GET_DATA, new     PowerPlantEvent($this->getPowerPlantAction($id)));
```

Call like this will not work, cuz I am missing some parameters.

and I have action in subscriber:

```
public function onPowerPlantGetData(PowerPlantEvent $event, $startDate, $endDate, $measurement, $field)
```

How to do that?

Comment: Can I dispach event like: $dispatcher->dispatch(Events::POWERPLANT_GET_DATA, new PowerPlantEvent($this->getPowerPlantAction($id)), $startDate, $endDate, $measurement, $field); Or is there some other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you event uses optional parameters, you can **make them optional in the constructor**.

```
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Event;

final class PowerPlantEvent extends Event
{
    /**
     * @var PowerPlantAction
     */
    private $powerPlantAction;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $startDate;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $endDate;

    /**
     * @var int
     */
    private $measurement;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $field;

    public function __construct(
        $powerPlantAction,
        $startDate = null,
        $endDate = null,
        $measurement = null,
        $field = null
    ) {
        $this->powerPlantAction = $powerPlantAction;
        $this->startDate = $startDate;
        $this->endDate = $endDate;
        $this->measurement = $measurement;
        $this->field = $field;
    }

    public function getPowerPlantAction()
    {
        return $this->powerPlantAction;
    }

    public function getStartDate()
    {
        return $this->startDate;
    }

    public function getEndDate()
    {
        return $this->endDate;
    }

    public function getMeasurement()
    {
        return $this->measurement;
    }

    public function getField()
    {
        return $this->field;
    }
}
```

Then dispatching like this:

```
$this->eventDispatcher->dispatch(
    Events::POWERPLANT_GET_DATA,
    new PowerPlantEvent($this->getPowerPlantAction($id))
);
```

Or:

```
$this->eventDispatcher->dispatch(
    Events::POWERPLANT_GET_DATA,
    new PowerPlantEvent(
       $this->getPowerPlantAction($id),
       $startDate,
       $endDate,
       $measurement,
       $field
    )
);
```

In your subscriber just use those getters:

```
public function onPowerPlantGetData(PowerPlantEvent $powerPlantEvent)
{
    $powerPlantEvent->getStartDate();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Tnx, I tried and it works fine. The documentation is poor on this part of events. I also think about creating new class or maybe command for this. Because with this i started the process of getting data thrue phenastalk job from another symfony app using influx database. Is the event the best way to implement this functionalty or it will be better using custom class or symfony command?

Comment: Good. I have few information to give you useful advice. I'd try both approaches and kept the one that suits you better. I personally prefer events. Command (in terminology of Command Bus) would be bigger architectural change with no added value here.

Answer (score 0):

You should put all necessary data into Event itself and then you can access them in subscriber

For simplicity I made properties public and added all to `__construct` but it's up to you how you implement it. You might want to create new Event class for that

```
class PowerPlantEvent extends Event
{
    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    public $startDate;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    public $endDate;

    /**
     * @var Something
     */
    public $measurement;

    public $field;

    /**
     * PowerPlantEvent constructor.
     *
     * @param \DateTime $startDate
     * @param \DateTime $endDate
     * @param Something $measurement
     * @param           $field
     */
    public function __construct(\DateTime $startDate, \DateTime $endDate, Something $measurement, $field)
    {
        $this->startDate = $startDate;
        $this->endDate = $endDate;
        $this->measurement = $measurement;
        $this->field = $field;
    }
}
```

and call it with

```
$dispatcher = $this->container->get('event_dispatcher');
$dispatcher->dispatch(
    Events::POWERPLANT_GET_DATA,
    new PowerPlantEvent($startDate, $endDate, $measurement, $field)
);
```

and access in subscriber (or event listener)

```
public function onPowerPlantGetData(PowerPlantEvent $event)
{
    $startDate = $event->startDate; // you might want to implement getters for those
}
```